# How can I modify the metadata for my token?

Tags: solana-program

How can I modify metadata in my token? Currently I am trying to modify it using solanas new method since they closed the GitHub repertory. Hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1):

If the metadata was created with the metaplex standard, then what you would is the instruction to update a metadata account.

You can do this either off-chain through the metaplex ts [sdk](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#update), or on-chain by CPI(here's a [reference](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions#update-a-metadata-account) to the instruction format).